# How to enable directory listing in Spring 4 with Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I know there is are global Tomcat settings, but is there an approach to define directory listing on application (context) level? I'd like to list static content from the directory, e.g. "webapp/images".

I do not have web.xml. The configuration is done in `WebAppIntializer` which extends `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` and everything is by default.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/37855/tomcat-serving-static-content-with-directory-listings could work for you if you'd be willing to add a web.xml.

Comment: @KorhanOzturk thx, but it will not work with embeded Tomcat, right?

Comment: are you using Spring's bootstrap?

Comment: Nope. As current solution we put nginx as a proxy and it will serve static content.